# Rewrite condition for /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all routes except /backend, /address and /customer to /account like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/backend.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/address.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/customer.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/account.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /account [L,R=301]
```

This works well except for the / route.

Comment: What's the point of a regexp if you want to redirect everything? Just use: `RewriteRule ^ /account [L,R=301]`

Comment: The only potential issue I can see here is your 301 permanent redirect may be running into caching issues in your browser from previous versions of your redirect.  Clear your cache, try your request in another browser, or try a site like web-sniffer.net to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I already tried it in different browser and cleared the cache, but the problem persists.